# jQuery -> toggle function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list with events. I use a foreach for the array to retrieve the data. How my list looks like:

```
<article class="club-list-club">
            <h2 class="club-list-title">
                <a href="'.url('clubs/'.$club->getSlug()).'">'.$club->getClubnaam().'</a>
            </h2>
            <h2 class="club-list-location">
                '.$club->getWoonplaats().'
            </h2>
            <h2 class="club-list-open-info">
                Openingstijden
            </h2>

            <h2 class="club-list-big-info">
                link2page
            </h2>
            <h2 class="club-list-small-info">
                <span class="club-list-show-small-info">Show</span>
            </h2>
            <div class="more-info hide">
                Hier wat informatie over de club zelf die kort word weergeven. je vind hier de openingstijden en alle
                andere belangrijke info. Hier wat informatie over de club zelf die kort word weergeven. je vind hier de
                openingstijden en alle andere belangrijke info.
            </div>
        </article>';
```

When the SPAN .club-list-show-small-info is clicked, i want the first div.more-info to toggle with fade or slide. What am i doing wrong in my code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.club-list-show-small-info').click(function(){
        $(this).next('div').slideToggle('.hide');
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

The click event is bound to the `span` element, the `div` is not its next sibling element, the `div` is the next sibling of the `span`s parent `h2` element. So

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.club-list-show-small-info').click(function () {
        $(this).parent().next('div').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LhT9C/)

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
$('.club-list-show-small-info').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().next().slideToggle();
});
```

Since the info you want to show and hide is the `next()` sibling of `.club-list-small-info` which is the `parent()` of your `.club-list-show-small-info` span

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pTHPL/)

If you want to have `fade` effect, you can use [fadeToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/):

```
$('.club-list-show-small-info').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().next().fadeToggle();
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pTHPL/1/)